# Ruby on Rails 3: HABTM with new controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to create a M:N relationship for a project-model that has_and_belongs_to _many users. A user can join many projects but projects also have many users. I guess I don't need a through cause my join table won't have another column.

So I included the association in my two models (has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
and  has_and_belongs_to_many :users) and set up a new migration:

```
class AddProjectsUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :projects_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :project, :user
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects_users
  end
end
```

That's working..
I'm not sure whether the next things are right or not - but I tried something.
I tried to create a new action in my user controller where I can set a relationship to this user to a project.

```
  def joinProject
    @user = current_user
    @user.projects = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Successfully joined project.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

It is probably the wrong way cause it says: "`undefined method 'each' for #<Project:0x00000103f10028>`"

**How can I else set this relationship?
Seems like I didn't really understand how this HABTM relationship is working..**

Can please anybody help me?

Some further information that may be interesting or wrong ;)

I created this route:

```
  match "joinProject_user/:id" => "users#joinProject", :as => :joinProject
```

And I called the controller action in my view as follows:

```
 <%= link_to 'Join', joinProject_path(project) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line of your controller action should be:

```
@user.projects += [Project.find(params[:id])]
```

or even

```
@user.project_ids += [params[:id]]
```

This will append the passed project to the existing project collection. The `User#projects=` method (defined by the habtm association) expects a collection not a Project object. Internally, it tries to call `each` so it fails since a Project doesn't respond to `each`.